# Get key values from a collection in Laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel, collections

I have this collection

```
1 => {#27
      +"id": 1
      +"name": "Zel"
      +"age": "43"
    }
2 => {#28
      +"id": 2
      +"name": "Kol"
      +"age": "56"
    }
3 => {#29
      +"id": 3
      +"name": "Mil"
      +"age": "32"
    }
```

and I would like to return an array with the key values as a string like this:

```
[
'id',
'name',
'age',
]
```

Can someone help me with that, please?

Comment: There is a [`keys`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-keys) method available on all Laravel collections which does what you want.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Laravel collection has a keys() method you could simply use it like this:

```
$keys = $collection->keys();
$get = $keys->all();
```

It is all clearly written in the [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-keys)

**EDIT**

After looking at your edit, my first consideration would be that if your collection is consistent you could get the first one and subsequently get the keys from there on:

```
$keys = $collection->first();
$get = $keys->keys()->all();
```

Or simply put `$collection->first()->keys()->all();`

**EDIT**

Here is how i was able to reproduce your problem:

```
$collection = collect([
    [
        'id' => 1, 
        'name' => 'Zel',
        'age' => 43
    ],
    [
        'id' => 2, 
        'name' => 'Kol',
        'age' => 56
    ],
    [
        'id' => 3, 
        'name' => 'Mil',
        'age' => 32
    ],
]);
$keys = collect($collection->first())->keys()->all();
```

Here is the Result I got:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => "id"
  1 => "name"
  2 => "age"
]
```

If it still returns a collection or an object based on your last comment, you could try any one of these:

```
$keys = $keys->toArray();
```

```
$keys = collect($keys)->toArray();
```

Comment: I am getting this Call to undefined method stdClass::keys()

Comment: Try this `collect($collection->first())->keys();`

Comment: Works - Thanksss, in the end I just cast it to array

Answer (score 1):

use `array_keys` :

```
$keys = array_keys($collection->first());
```